# How to match the columns with the divisions of the axis Y in a Histogram chart .rdlc file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, histogram, rdlc

I'm just trying to match the markers (blue arrows) with the division of axis Y (red arrows).

[image: Histogram example]

I tried this by modifying the property values of the property 'Custom Attributes'. I couldn't do it so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I change the property 'DrawSideBySide' to False, all columns will match the division of axis Y!.

... yup.. pretty dummy of my part but at least I found the answer